# How to list all symbols in mxnet?

Tags: python, mxnet

In mxnet 1.4 using the Python API, suppose I do

```
import mxnet as mx

tmp = mx.sym.var('a')
print(tmp)  # <Symbol a>

tmp = tmp + tmp
print(tmp)  # <Symbol _plus0>

tmp = mx.sym.var('b')
tmp = tmp + tmp
print(tmp)  # <Symbol _plus1>
```

I assume, `<Symbol _plus0>` is still present in the graph somewhere. How can I list all symbols which currently live in my graph?

I would like  to do something like `mx.sym.list_all_symbols()`.

I have checked this [tutorial](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/versions/master/tutorials/basic/symbol.htm), the [docs](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/symbol/symbol.html), as well as the [source code](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/blob/master/python/mxnet/symbol/symbol.py) but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mxnet`'s `viz` module to plot the network. You can also save the symbol graph to a json file and peruse the json file to view all the symbols -

```py
import mxnet as mx
a = mx.sym.Variable('a')
b = mx.sym.Variable('b')
c = a + b
d = a * b
# matrix multiplication
e = mx.sym.dot(a, b)
# reshape
f = mx.sym.reshape(d+e, shape=(1,4))
# plot
f.save('fgraph-symbol.json')
mx.viz.plot_network(symbol=f)
```

[The graph that gets plotted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGaYB.png)

Edit :

If you want the list the symbols and not just the names, then you should use `get_internals()` function. Run

```py
print(f.get_internals())
```

you will get a symbol group containing a list of all the symbol outputs. you can then access the individual symbols using their index in the group -

```
<Symbol group [a, b, _mul11, dot24, _plus51, reshape24]>
```

You can also walk through the graph using `f.get_children()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But that does not really give me programmatic access to them. Assume I would want to apply some function to each of the symbols in my graph.

Comment: if you want the symbols, then your best bet is to use `get_internals` method. Run `print(f.get_internals())` you will get a symbol group containing a list of all the symbol outputs - `<Symbol group [a, b, _mul11, dot24, _plus51, reshape24]>`. You can also walk though the graph using `f.get_children()`.